# Java 8 MySQL 8.0 with Connector/J JDBC query for between two timestamps always returns no results

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to find a set of similar records using a prepared statement definition of:

```
"SELECT id , date_time FROM event 
 WHERE (( personnel_id =? ) AND ( date_time BETWEEN ? AND ? ))"
```

The id and personnel_id are both integer in the table definition. The date_time in the table definition is a datetime.  The result set is always empty.

If I run the same query from MySQL Workbench it finds the records.

I've tried variations of this using UNIX_TIMESTAMP for the bounds and with Strings with the same result.  All the variants work in Workbench.

What am I missing here? I've looked at all the similar postings and none of them worked for me.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Timestamp date_time = record.getDateTime();
long baseTime = date_time.getTime();
long geTime = baseTime - 2000L;
long leTime = baseTime + 2000L;
Timestamp geStamp = new Timestamp( geTime );
Timestamp leStamp = new Timestamp( leTime );
stmt = mySqlConn.prepareStatement( candidateQuery );
      stmt.setInt( 1 , perId );
      stmt.setTimestamp( 2 , geTime );
      stmt.setTimestamp( 3 , leTime );
```

Comment: I recommend you switch to using `LocalDateTime` (use `setObject`) instead of `Timestamp`.

Comment: It needs to be a UTC comparison as part of the requirements.  I changed my connect to set the session timezone to UTC.  It works fine for equality, but not for BETWEEN.